Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path Strands. in coq
I have coq file and was working on it for days but now the file giving me following error:
Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path Strands.

also the required packages are as under:
Require Import Lia.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import Coq.Lists.List.ListNotations.
Require Import Strands.
Require Import Bundles.
Require Import Terms.
Require Import StrandTactics.
Require Import Penetrator.
Require Import MinimalMPT.
Set Implicit Arguments.

I tried changing and removing some packages restart the code but nothing works.

Maybe you have deleted/mangled the _CoqProject file?  --  Supporting these issues is already very difficult without access to the machine (given also the Coq ecosystem is very fragile), but your question is just very low quality: let's not even mention the formatting, but you don't even make clear if you are using CoqIDE vs VSCode and with which plugin, you just tag them all...?  -- Have you updated any of that software lately, or moved files around, and have you checked your _CoqProject file?

Here is documentation about the load path for compiled modules. https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.19.0/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html?highlight=loadpath#coq:exn.Cannot-find-library-foo-in-loadpath

If you go in an empty directory and run the command.
Require Import toto.

You get the error message
Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path toto.

So this is just to say, that you have no compiled file of your development in your current directory with the name Strands.vo
This may be due to the fact that you removed the files (for instance with a make clean command).  On my machine, it is usually enough to run make to restore a good state to the current dictory, but I don't know what is your working environment.

make does not even exist on Windows.  And the OP is clearly talking of something that was working before.  Rather, it is enough to upgrade to coq-lsp plugin, because lately it does not honour the _CoqProject file... talking of probable of course, the OP seems to have abandoned this.
